# ActiveRecord - Getting all Attributes of a Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating a gem that has to work with any possible combination of how the attributes on a Table would be configured - the specific case I'm using it for is Feedback, so we'll use that in this example:

Given the following item:

```
Feedback {
  :id => 1,
  :comments => "Works well",
  :recommendations => "Change this one thing"
}
```

I would have to extract the data as `{id: 1, comments: "Works Well", recommendations: "Change this one thing"}`, which if I know the particular fields Im dealing with is a no brainer. Unfortunately I need this to play nicely with any arrangement or collection of fields on the Feedback table.

So my question is this: Does Rails or ActiveRecord have a method that will allow me to simply grab all of the fields and the relevant data in a hash / is there a way to iterate over the values of an item in the database with ActiveRecord. I've tried converting the item to a Hash, using the to_params method on it, and other typical tricks for grabbing both the keys and values in key/value pairs, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: `Feedback.first.attributes` and you are done..

Comment: `Feedback.first.as_json` would do as well, with an option to pass extra options like `Feedback.first.as_json(include: :association)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) method.

Like `Feedback.first.attributes` and you are done.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`columns_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache.html#method-i-columns_hash) class method on any active_record model.

```
Feedback.columns_hash
```

or if you just need the names of the columns, use [`column_names`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-column_names)

```
Feedback.column_names
```

you can use [`content_columns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-content_columns) to get only the columns that contains data, so any column, ending with _id, _count will be removed from the collection.

```
Feedback.content_columns
```